# Why does Bash silently ignore non-existing .env file when using "source .env" or ". .env"?

Tags: bash, shell

Who can explain this weird behavior?

UPDATE: I cannot reproduce this

- in an ubuntu:18.04 or ubuntu:20.04 Docker container, or
- running as root, using `sudo -i`.

So maybe it's something weird in my .bashrc.

```bash
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

mkdir /tmp/test-env
cd /tmp/test-env/

# Works as expected
. .whatever
-bash: .whatever: No such file or directory
source .whatever
-bash: .whatever: No such file or directory

# Works as expected
. ./.whatever
-bash: ./.whatever: No such file or directory
source ./.whatever
-bash: ./.whatever: No such file or directory


# Works as expected
. ./.env
-bash: ./.env: No such file or directory
source ./.env
-bash: ./.env: No such file or directory


# Not working as expected - why doesn't bash complain?!
. .env
# No error message
echo $?
0
source .env
# No error message
echo $?
0


which .env
# No output, so it's not a global command.
```

Comment: From the bash man-page for the `source` command: _If filename does not contain a slash, filenames  in PATH  are used to find the directory containing filename_. This may explain the difference between `source .xx` and `source ./.xx`. However, a non existing file will always produce an error message, if you try to source it.

Comment: Thanks - My current idea is that I have some weird stuff in my .bashrc that swallows the error. Will try to comment out stuff and find out.